For any continuous function, does the sequence of piecewise straight line approximations, converge pointwise to the original function?
Let $f: [0,1)\to [0,1)$ be a bounded continuous real function.
Here, in $f^n(x),$ $n$ is a superscript index, not $n-$th derivative or $n-$th power or anything else.
For each $n\in\mathbb{N},\ $ for each $i\in \{1,2,\ldots, n\},$ define $ f_{i}^{n}(x):= \text{ a straight line with domain } I_{i}^{n}:\left[ \frac{i-1}{n}, \frac{i}{n} \right)$ which minimises $\displaystyle\sup_{x\in I_i^n} \left\lvert f(x) - f_{i}^{n}(x) \right\rvert.$ For each $n\in\mathbb{N},\ $ let $f^n(x):= f_{i}^{n}(x)$ if $x\in I_i^n$ (for each $i\in \{1,2,\ldots, n\}).$ Is it true then that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} f^n(x) = f(x)$ (pointwise)?
This feels like a well-known theorem, or perhaps a consequence of a theorem to do with uniform convergence of sequences of function, but I have maybe not come across it in this format.

$(f^n)$ converges uniformly to $f$ on every interval $[0, a] \subset [0, 1)$, so that in particular $f^n(x) \to f(x)$ pointwise on $[0, 1)$.
Choose some $a'$ with $a < a' < 1$. $f$ is continuous and therefore uniformly continuous on the compact interval $[0, a']$. Given $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta > 0$ such that
$$
 \forall x, y \in [0, a']: \, |x-y| < \delta \implies |f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon \, .
$$
Now choose a positive integer $N$ such that $a+1/N < a'$ and $1/N < \delta$. If $n \ge N$ then
$$
\sup_{x\in I_i^n} | f(x) - f_{i}^{n}(x) | \le \sup_{x\in I_i^n} | f(x) - f((i-1)/n) | < \epsilon
$$
for all intervals $I_i^n \subset [0, a')$. In particular is $|f(x) - f^n(x)| < \epsilon$ for $x \in [0, a]$ and $n \ge N$, and that proves the uniform convergence.
